# Proving the existing of Least Upper Bound (Rudin PMA Definition 1.8)

Tags: real-analysis

Definition 1.8 of Walter Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis lays out in the following words

"Suppose there exists an $\alpha \in S$ with the following properties:

1. $\alpha$ is an upper bound of E
2. if $\gamma \le \alpha$ then $\gamma$ is not an upper bound of E

Then $\alpha$ is called the ...."

**I have two questions here (perhaps related):**

1. Can we interprete this entire definition this way that for us to prove there is an LUB for set E, we have to prove 5 conditions:

a. $S$ is an ordered set,

b. E, the "hero-set of our analysis" is a subset of $S$, and is bounded above

c. E is not empty (not part of definition 1.7 or 1.8, picked from 1.10)

d. $\alpha$ satisfies the conditions of Definition 1.7, implying all elements $x \in E : x \leq \alpha$

e. Any element less than $\alpha$ is no longer an upper bound

2. The second question is - would it be prudent for me to read Definition 1.8 and 1.10 together as this:
   "Suppose S is an ordered set with LUB property, $E \subset S$,and E is bounded above - **there exists a special element** $\alpha$..."

So this interpretation means that it is guaranteed for this special element to exist for every subset of S if $S$ is an ordered set with LUB property.

Comment: Whether or not we need $(c)$ thought-provoking. Based on Rudin's definitions, (it is vacuously true that) the empty set is bounded above. Therefore for any ordered set $S$ we can take $E=\emptyset.$ Then, for any $\alpha\in S,\ 1.8(i),(ii)\ $ are both satisfied (they are both vacuously true), and therefore every $\alpha\in S$ is the least upper bound of $E=\emptyset,$ making the concept of "least upper bound" not as what was intended, right? So I think that Rudin should probably have defined $E$ to be nonempty in definition $1.7,$ or at least definition $1.8.$

Comment: That all said, I do think discussions like this are usually beating around the bush. Whether or not you include "empty set" in part of definitions is rarely illuminating.

Comment: I think proving it to be a non-empty set is to ensure my proofs are complete. I am more concerned about the path we take to prove $\alpha$ is an LUB. I am teaching myself analysis, so I am trying to be as rigorous as possible in absence of a formal teacher.

Comment: OK, that's fair enough. I will give your question more thought.